# X509TrustManagerの警告について

Tags: android

GooglePlayから以下のメールが届きました。
作成したアプリは、クラッシュレポート機能を実装しているため『org.acra.』をimportしていますが、
実際は、『org.acra.util.NaiveTrustManager;』は使用していないにも関わらずが警告されています。
この場合でも、アプリを変更する必要があるのでしょうか？
また、どのような対応が必要なのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教授お願いします。

---

Google Play warning: You are using an unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager

Your app(s) listed at the end of this email use an unsafe implementation of the interface X509TrustManager. Specifically, the implementation ignores all SSL certificate validation errors when establishing an HTTPS connection to a remote host, thereby making your app vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. An attacker could read transmitted data (such as login credentials) and even change the data transmitted on the HTTPS connection. If you have more than 20 affected apps in your account, please check the Developer Console for a full list. 
To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code in the checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager interface to raise either CertificateException or IllegalArgumentException whenever the certificate presented by the server does not meet your expectations. For technical questions, you can post to Stack Overflow and use the tags “android-security” and “TrustManager.”
Please address this issue as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Beginning May 17, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates containing the unsafe implementation of the interface X509TrustManager.
To confirm you’ve made the correct changes, submit the updated version of your app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.

---

Comment: Softさんのコードの中で、`X509TrustManager`はどこで使われているのでしょうか。

Comment: >summeaさん
X509TrustManagerは使用していません。（使用していないつもりです）
org.acra.util.NaiveTrustManager;
GooglePlayからのメールでは、上記の部分で指摘をされているのですが、
当方のアプリでは、上記を使用していません。
org.acra.*をインポートしていることで、org.acra.util.NaiveTrustManager;も
使用していると判断されてしまうのでしょうか。基本的な知識不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: ACRAライブラリをバージョンアップする事で対応できる。